# Is there a way to check if one or more rows of a result set sum up to a specific value?

Tags: c#, sql, algorithm, postgresql

This is kind of a complicated question to phrase so bear with me.  Let's say I have a query that return a set of integers.

`2387

3357

3471

4885

5867

6170

8170

9777

12970

13190

17670

20470

160159`

These obvious all mean something to me, even if it's tough to see how they do for you.  For ease, they represent a measurement.  Now my first try is to match a specific database values to a number obtained through an upload process  In this case I want to match `37,174`

Now, obviously, by looking at you can see that no ONE record matches the amount I'm looking for.  My real question would be, is there any way to see if some combination of certain amounts would total to the amount I'm looking for.  I'm looking for something that would preferably be able to be rolled into a SQL query, but I use C# for all of my processing, so if there is something that I'm missing that I can utilize, a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.  I tried a Google search, and because of the delicacy of phrasing the question, I could not find anything relevant/useful.  Still a newbie, so I don't know if there is just a method or a class in C# or some functionality of Postgres that will permit this.

Edit** I know how I could do it using loops, but I know that that would be a poor performance choice.

Comment: Is the number of measurements known? finite?

Comment: It's energy meter usage.  So if someone uses X amount of Killowatt hours a month, that number is represented in the result set.  But the 37,174 is given later, and it's always possible for it to be an aggregated value.

Comment: This is a knapsack problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) with equality constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Combinatronics Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G):

```
var values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var target = 9;
var candidates = Enumerable.Range(1,values.Count())
                           .SelectMany(x => new Combinations<int>(values, x))
                           .Where(x => x.Sum() == target);
```

This will give you all possible combinations which match your target value.  It's up to you if you'd prefer the first one (use `FirstOrDefault()`), or apply some more logic.

In your example, no combination adds up to `37174`.

Comment: This does exactly what I want, and gives me the freedom to evaluate more than one possible match.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this in SQL is a brute force approach.  For instance, the following query will consider all combinations of three numbers:

```
select *
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.val < t2.val join
     t.t3
     on t2.val < t3.val
where t1.val + t2.val + t3.val = 37174;
```

The combinations are ordered from smallest to largest values, with no duplicates.

If you want the *closest* sum to your goal, then you can do something like:

```
select 
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.val < t2.val join
     t.t3
     on t2.val < t3.val
order by abs(t1.val + t2.val + t3.val - 37174)
limit 1;
```

If you want up-to three numbers, then include a 0 value in the list.

And, all of these generalize to a fixed number of joins.

To do a variable number, you need to use recursive queries.

You do have one advantage using SQL over, say, C# for this type of search.  SQL can take advantage of multi-threaded parallelism by default.

Comment: Maybe a `WITH RECURSIVE` query instead of brute force?

Answer (score 1):

As the numbers increase, the number of options increase exponentially.

Eg:

If you have three numbers, then you have to check 7 combinations

```
A, B, C, A+B, A+C, B+C, A+B+C
```

With four, there are

```
A, B, C, D, 
A+B, A+C, A+D, B+C, B+D, C+D,
A+B+C, A+B+D, A+C+D, B+C+D
A+B+C+D
```

and so on.

So I would say, No, there is no simple SQL way to absolutely find the answer.

However, you could do it with a cross join to find the simpler solutions.

Eg : where your table is `t` with a field i containing the values, add a 0 figure to the results and...

```
insert t (i)
select 0 union
select 2387 union
select 3357 union
select  3471 union
select  4885 union
select  5867 union
select  6170 union
select 8170 union
select  9777 union
select  12970 union
select  13190 union
select  17670 union
select  20470 union
select  160159

select *, t1.i + t2.i + t3.i + t4.i + t5.i + t6.i + t7.i
 from t t1
    cross join t t2 
    cross join t t3 
    cross join t t4 
    cross join t t5
    cross join t t6
    cross join t t7
where t1.i+t2.i+t3.i+t4.i+t5.i+t6.i+t7.i = 37174
```

Which will give you the combination...

```
2387    3471    4885    13190   4885    4885    3471
```

Now you may have the restriction that duplicates aren't allowed, in which case there is no solution from your data

Comment: Given the domain of the problem, duplicates are probably not allowed.  But this is the one viable combination to produce that result.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE match(val, res) AS
(SELECT st.val , 1234 - st.val as res
 FROM your_table st
 WHERE 1234 - st.val >= 0
 UNION ALL
 SELECT nt.val,  match.res - nt.val 
 FROM your_table nt
 JOIN match ON match.res - nt.val >= 0
),

 final_match (val, res) AS
(SELECT match.val , match.res
 FROM match 
 WHERE match.res = 0
 UNION ALL
 SELECT match.val,  match.res
 FROM match
 JOIN final_match ON final_match.val = match.res
)

SELECT *
FROM final_match
ORDER BY res DESC;
```

The idea - to build recursively all combinations of numbers, that can lead to your sum.
Then pick one, that has `your_number - sum = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server syntax - I don't know if there's a postgres equivalent of recursive CTEs

```
;with cte as
(
    select  cast(val as varchar(MAX)) as valtxt
    ,       val
    ,       val as summed
    from #temp

    union all
    select  C.valtxt +' + ' + CAST(C2.val as varchar(max))
    ,       C2.val
    ,       C.summed + C2.val
    from cte C
    inner join #temp C2
    on c.val < C2.val
    where C.summed <= 37174
)
select top 1 valtxt, summed from cte order by ABS(summed - 37174)
```

(where #temp is the table containing the values)